# How do you handle range-date selection in postgresql?

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, query-performance

I have a table with hundreds of thousands rows in it, and I have a necessity to select rows that were created in a certain date range, and this might be the only 'where' clause. Is there any acceptable way to increase query performance? 
Do I need daily(or maybe more often) table CLUSTERing upon b-tree index if this 'date_created' field is allways increasing in all inserted rows?

Comment: Did you add an index on date_created?

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic case for partitioning on the date column you are filtering on.

The documentation describes the process in more detail, but in summary:

- Create a child table which inherits its structure from the current table
- Create a check constraint limiting the date range which can be stored in the child table
- Either insert into a "current" partition and then rename it as appropriate or set up triggers on the parent table to push inserted rows to the relevant partitions

Only partitions which are within the date range you specify will then the scanned during query execution - with significant performance gains.